# Long term archive image compression

Tags: image, compression, archive, image-compression

My experiance with normal archive types for data such as zip/gzip/7zip/lzma/etc.. dont do a good job of image compression

I was wondering if there exists image compression that allow for a very high compression ratio for long term storage, in which the image doesnt need to contain enough data to preview or "look" at the picture, just ensure that the data is reproducable to a normal jpeg/png?

When searching for image compression algorithms, google basically only returns jpeg,png,gif,bitmap. As far as I understand these image types are for compressing images that need to be viewable in their compressed format. But if you didnt need to view it the image when its compressed could you achieve a higher compression ratio.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PNG optimized with [ZopfliPNG](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/) (e.g. via GUI like [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com)) will give you pretty good lossless compression.

PNG has prediction filters that help it achieve better compression than bare gzip.